# Javascript variable in string output?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, variables

The variable x is getting the current url. I need to then put this url into the spot where the xxxx is. How would I go about doing this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      function postListen()
       {
    var x = ( document.URL ); 
          FB.api(
            &#39;/me/beatmushroom:listen&#39;,
            &#39;post&#39;,
            { song:  xxxx},
            function(response) {
               if (!response || response.error) {
                  alert(&#39;Error occured&#39;);
       } else {
          alert(&#39;Listen was successful! Action ID: &#39; + response.id);
       }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the variable in the object literal. While the key is always a string (even without quotes), the value can be any JavaScript epxression:

```
{ recipe: x },
```

Comment: It does not work for some reason. I think the url has to be in quotes { recipe: 'url'}

Comment: No, it does not (quoting it would turn it into a string and thus not use the value of the variable anymore). If it doesn't work show your new code and if you get any error.

Comment: I replaced the xxxx with x but I get an error, meaning that something went wrong and facebook did not like what I was sending it. It works if I manually put the pages url in with quotes.

Comment: Maybe facebook doesn't like your value.

Comment: Then **update your question to show the new code you have**. Otherwise we can only make guesses.

Comment: Ill make a new question since this one has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `'xxxx'` with the variable `x`

```
function postCook() {
    var x = ( document.URL );
    FB.api(
        '/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook',
        'post',
        { recipe: x },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        }
    );
}
```